# Write Ajax Returned Data On Button Press

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a Summary Report data handler (dhSummaryReport.ashx) that returns json data as follows:

```
{"iTotalRecords":1,"aaData":[{"val1Total":3,"val2Total":6,"val3Total":0}]}
```

I have a webpage that I want to display the above results to a series of input labels (Simplified version as follows):

```
<div class="row">
    <input id="txtStartDate" type="text" class="form-control date-picker"/>
    <input id="txtEndDate" type="text" class="form-control date-picker"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="name">Monthly Totals</div>
    <div class="value"><label id="lblVal1Total">0</label></div>
    <div class="value"><label id="lblVal2Total">0</label></div>
    <div class="value"><label id="lblVal3Total">0</label></div>
</div>
```

I have the following jQuery code that runs an ajax call to the data handler. The values are successfully returned (I can see them as I step through the code), but the web page is not updated with the new numbers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Search Button Press
        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {

            // Collect Parameter Input Values
            var dStartDate = $('#txtStartDate').val();
            var dEndDate = $('#txtEndDate').val();

            // Run Data Handler Query
            $.ajax({
                url: "dhSummaryReport.ashx",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                    startDate: dStartDate,
                    endDate: dEndDate
                },
                responseType: "json",
                success: OnViewComplete,
                error: OnViewFail
            });
            return false;

            function OnViewComplete(result) {

                //Cycle Through JSON Rows
                $.each(result.aaData, function (i, row) {
                    $('#lblVal1Total').val(row.val1Total);
                    $('#lblVal2Total').val(row.val2Total);
                    $('#lblVal3Total').val(row.val3Total);
                });

            }

            function OnViewFail(result) {
                alert('Request Failed');
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Why isn't the webpage updating with the new values? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write with `text()` or `html()` because `val()` is for form inputs

```
 //Cycle Through JSON Rows
 $.each(result.aaData, function (i, row) {
      $('#lblVal1Total').text(row.val1Total);
      $('#lblVal2Total').text(row.val2Total);
      $('#lblVal3Total').text(row.val3Total);
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

`<label>` elements don't have a `value` property, hence you cannot use `.val`. Use `.text` to update the elements.

Answer (score 1):

use `html` method to update the label text.

```
   $('#lblVal1Total').html(row.val1Total);
   $('#lblVal2Total').html(row.val2Total);
   $('#lblVal3Total').html(row.val3Total);
```